# how to pass html checkbox arrays to controller in route laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, model-view-controller

I have a problem with Laravel framework .... I Have an HTML array of checkboxes in my Laravel view file like below:

```
 @foreach($jobs as $job) 
     <input type="checkbox" name="jobs[]" value="{{$user->id}}">
 @endforeach 
//$jobs variable pointing to read records from jobs table in database
```

I want to pass "jobs" element to my Controller from the route file But I don't want to use jQuery to do it. (Should be passed with **Get** Method].

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form method="get" action="{{route('some.route')}}">
@foreach($jobs as $job) <input type="checkbox" name="jobs[]" value="{{$user->id}}">
@endforeach
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('some/route','yourcontroller@somemethod')->name('some.route')
```

**yourcontroller.php**

```
public function somemethod(Request $request){
  dd($request->get('jobs'));
  //you an store it in database now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question, in order to pass data from your input to the controller you need to have a `<form>` that contains it, and set your `method` attribute to `GET`. From there, you can make a Route that will accept a parameter.

[Read the Routing docs here.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters)